# Will Kadane's Algorithm work on an array of run length encoded integers?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, run-length-encoding, kadanes-algorithm

Let's say max_sequence(Array A): is a solution of Kadane's algorithm.

you have an array:5,-3,-4,8,-1,12,-6,+4,+4,-14,+2,+8

and you shorten this array down to streaks of positive and negative sequences:

so now the array is: +5,-7+8,-1,+12,-6,+8,-14+10

the max sequence returned is the same for both arrays.

Can you prove mathematically that there is / is not, a sequence of integers (containing at least one positive integer) that return different outputs from the function max_sequence?

Comment: This should be asked on [cs.se]

Answer (score 1):

If the max_sequence contains one of the positive values in a contiguous subsequence of positive values then it contains all of the contiguous positive values, otherwise it would not be maximal. [Reductio ad absurdum]

if the max_sequence contains one of the negative values in a contiguous subsequence of negative values then it contains all of the contiguous negative values AND both of the enclosing positive values and all of their positive successors or predecessors, otherwise it would not be maximal. [Reductio ad absurdum]

Therefore the run-length-encoded version produces the same result as the non-run-length encoded version.